# Math.random and FileReader

Tags: java, file, random

I'm trying to make a program which randomly get a line from a file, I have finished my code but I get weird results, for example if I get the line 0 it says "null" same with line 6, 7, 8, 9... but when I get number 5 I get last line (Pink), when I get number 4 I get line 7 (Brown), number 2 line 3 (Navy) and so on. My file "archivo.txt" has 10 lines like this:

- Red
- Orange
- Blue
- Navy
- Lime
- Green
- Olive
- Brown
- Yellow
- Pink

And this is my code:

```
    public static String getLinea(){
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String linea = null;
    int numeroRandom = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println(numeroRandom);
    try{
        archivo = new File("C:\\archivo.txt");
        fr = new FileReader (archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        for(int i = 0; i < numeroRandom; i++){
            br.readLine();
            linea = br.readLine();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }finally{
        try{
            if(null != fr){
                fr.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return linea;

}
 public static void main(String[] args){
     String linea;
     linea = getLinea();
     System.out.println(linea);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to readLine from the buffer two times in sequence.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < numeroRandom; i++){
        br.readLine();
        linea = br.readLine();

    }
```

instead just read once. Correct way  :

```
for(int i = 0; i < numeroRandom; i++){
        linea = br.readLine();

    }
```

Also you should check if BufferedReader has any more data left before reading from the buffered reader. This can be done as follows:

```
while(((linea = br.readLine()) != null) &&  i < numeroRandom)
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Meh, I copy-pasted the code and I didnt realize about that, thank you!

Comment: @user3313820 Glad it worked for you. You can mark the Answer as accepted and close the question if it worked

Answer (score 1):

You are calling readLine() twice in your loop, effectively doubling the number of lines you are skipping.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to read only the nth line, skipping the previous ones. Then you should update this piece of code:

```
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    for(int i = 0; i < numeroRandom; i++){
        br.readLine();
        linea = br.readLine();

    }
```

Into this:

```
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    for(int i = 0; i < numeroRandom; i++){
        br.readLine();
    }
    linea = br.readLine(); // move this line
```

You were getting `null` when `numeroRandom` was 0 because `linea` wasn't being updated. The other strange results happened because you were reading 2 lines in each cycle. There will be a point where `getLine()` will simply return null from not having more lines to read.